# Not receiving touchesEnded/Moved/Cancelled after adding subView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitouch

Title more or less says it all.  In response to a `touchesBegan` event, my `UIViewController` recolours itself and adds some subviews.

It never receives the `touchesEnded`.  I guess because the added subviews are somehow intercepting the event.  I tried calling `resignFirstResponder` on the subviews to no avail.

The code works fine when I don't add the child views and the touch events are called as normal.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: Bit of detail and how I fixed it.

Basically I had a master view with some subviews, when I touched the subview, the event would be passed through to the master view, however, on this event I was removing the subviews and adding new ones in their place. The fact that the touch originated on a subview which no longer existed meant that the rest of the touch was lost.

I fixed this by overriding hitTest:withEvent in my master view, to stop touches ever getting tested against the subviews

Comment: Hmmm, well the code is quite complex, but I coded up the simplest possible example to post up here and it worked OK... so +1 for the nudge in the right direction.............. will post when I've figured out the difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO for the subview before adding it as a subview ?

Comment: Maybe some subview(s) consumed that event by implementing a ill-formed -touchesEnded:withEvent ?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need pass the touch from the subview onto the superview using something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: the subviews don't receive the event either. If I add a subview to the place where the touchesBegan event occurred, neither the subview nor the superview receive touchesMoved/Cancelled/Ended

Comment: This passes the touch to the superCLASS, not the superVIEW. ;)